# How to add an Interceptor from a lazy loaded module to application Interceptors array on Angular 4/5?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services, angular-http-interceptors

I have `AppModule` and `LazyLoadedModule`. What I want from each module components is:

1. Requests from AppModule components use **LoggerInterceptor** and **UrlInterceptor**;
2. Requests from LazyLoadedModule components use **LoggerInterceptor**, **UrlInterceptor** and also ***FilterInterceptor***.

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
     {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: LoggerInterceptor,multi: true},
     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: UrlInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

lazy-loaded.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LazyLoadedComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: FilterInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
})
export class LazyLoadedModule {}
```

The problem is that **when LazyLoadedModule is lazy loaded, FilterInterceptor is not included** to the interceptors thread, like it was never injected.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem, my use case is slightly different but it might work for you.
My scenario:
- I have a feature module for integration with third party, this third party API has bearer token authentication, so I set in on my interceptor.

if you only provide the interceptor from your feature module, it won't get called, similarly if you provide it from your AppModule it would work.

The fix for me was reimporting the HttpClientModule in the feature module and it worked.

You should however carefully test that when reimporting HttpClientModule, the interceptors provided in AppModule still work

Comment: I'll try this out. I've seen this answer in another place, but I doesn't look like it should work like this. HttpClientModule is a one time importer module. Anyway, I'll let you know. Thanks for now :)